# Get internal path from shared link

Tags: dropbox-api

Now with the v2 API, is there still no way to get the internal file path from a public shared URL?

I guess I could use [get_shared_links](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http#documentation-sharing-get_shared_links) and iterate over the results until I find the one I want, but this seems very wasteful. Is there a better way?

Comment: This is possible using the Core API /metadata/link endpoint: https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#metadata-link There isn't an API v2 equivalent yet, so you may want to use /metadata/link for now.

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox API v2 now offers this via the endpoint /sharing/get_shared_link_metadata:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-get_shared_link_metadata